# How can I get the multiple texts from two sets of parentheses?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get multiple texts from more than one set of parentheses, and if there is no more than one set then I need to get text from only that single set of parentheses.

1) Example :

```
My sentence is :
                  A Cef (1000mg) (Sterlie Ceftriaxone) Price List.
```

Now, I need to get the output like this :

```
  Output :
                 1000mg Sterlie Ceftriaxone
```

2) Also if I have only single set like this : Aamin A (Atenolol) Price List.

Then my output should be :   Atenolol

I am using this javascript code :

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "A Cef (1000mg) (Sterlie Ceftriaxone) Price List."; 
    var res = str.match(/\((.*))\)/);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[1];
}
```

It is perfectly working for the 2nd case but when I am using it for the 1st one it giving me this output.

```
         Output :1000mg) (Sterlie Ceftriaxone
```

Comment: I think you have too many brakets on the right hand side. Try this `var res = str.match(/\((.*)\)/);`

Comment: i have used same expression as u suggested. Its not working for 1st one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a non-greedy expression `/\((.+?)\)/gm`.
See https://regex101.com/r/OKvbXy/1

```js
function myFunction(text) {
    var res = text.match(/\((.+?)\)/g);
    var cleanedUp = res.join(' ').replace(/[()]/g,''); // remove () and join matches
    console.log( cleanedUp );
}

myFunction("A Cef (1000mg) (Sterlie Ceftriaxone) Price List.");
myFunction("Aamin A (Atenolol) Price List.");
```

---

Btw, your code has nothing to do with jQuery (*you are not even using it in your code*)

Answer (score 1):

It's because * is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/7947020). You also want to do a [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) match to get all results.

Try this instead -

`str.match(/\(([^\)]+)\)/g)`

Answer (score 0):

I belive the issue is that by using the `.*` (wildcard) you are capturing the brackets *and* the spaces.

If you use `var res = str.match(/\(([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\)/);` instead, it will work to capture the first group, as it will not match the brackets or whitespace in your example.